# What's better to use: a DataGrid or ListView for displaying large amounts of data?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, datagridview

I want to display >50000 rows in a table. Which is the best control to use: a DataGrid or a ListView (in details view)? Which of these controls will have the better performance?

Comment: Why don't you display paged data instead of showing > 50000 rows all together.

Comment: There is no 'better' with numbers like this.  Better is 50 rows, the number of rows you can expect a human to read without wanting to uninstall your program.

Comment: Test both solutions and see results. I recently used DataGridView for displaying over 300k rows - if a user makes data selection like this - and haven't noticed any performance issues (if you disable column's autoresizeing). Of course there are some delays, but for such larage ammount of data - acceptable. All depends on your project.

Comment: LOL +1 @mj82 for "Of course there are some delays"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As Hans says in a comment to the original question, they're both going to have abysmal performance, surpassed only by the displeasure that your users will surely experience at the insanity of so many lines of data being displayed at the same time.

But if this is unavoidable in your application (and you provide a *very* good search function), then you should strongly consider using the **virtual mode** option, regardless of which control you decide to use. This means that you must provide your own data-management operations, rather than relying on the control to do it for you. The advantage is that things are much faster. As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode.aspx) says:

> Virtual mode is designed for use with very large stores of data. When the `VirtualMode` property is true, you create a `DataGridView` with a set number of rows and columns and then handle the [`CellValueNeeded` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalueneeded.aspx) to populate the cells. Virtual mode requires implementation of an underlying data cache to handle the population, editing, and deletion of DataGridView cells based on actions of the user. For more information about implementing virtual mode, see [How to: Implement Virtual Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b177d6d.aspx).

Or, for the [`ListView` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx):

> Setting the `VirtualMode` property to true puts the `ListView` into virtual mode. In Virtual mode, the normal [`Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items.aspx) collection is unused. Instead, [`ListViewItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.aspx) objects are created dynamically as the ListView requires them.
>
> Virtual mode can be useful under many circumstances. If a `ListView` object must be populated from a very large collection already in memory, creating a `ListViewItem` object for each entry can be wasteful. In virtual mode, only the items required are created. In other cases, the values of the `ListViewItem` objects may need to be recalculated frequently, and doing this for the whole collection would produce unacceptable performance. In virtual mode, only the required items are calculated.
>
> In order to use virtual mode, you must handle the [`RetrieveVirtualItem` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.retrievevirtualitem.aspx), which is raised every time the `ListView` requires an item. This event handler should create the `ListViewItem` object that belongs at the specified index. In addition, the [`VirtualListSize` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtuallistsize.aspx) must be set to the size of the virtual list.
>
> Handling the [`SearchForVirtualItem` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.searchforvirtualitem.aspx) enables searching in virtual mode. If this event is not handled, the [`FindItemWithText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.finditemwithtext.aspx) and [`FindNearestItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.findnearestitem.aspx) methods will return null.
>
> You can handle the [`CacheVirtualItems` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.cachevirtualitems.aspx) in order to maintain a cache of `ListViewItem` objects. If the calculation or lookup to create a `ListViewItem` object is expensive, maintaining a cache can improve performance.
>
> If the [`View` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view.aspx) is set to Tile, the value will automatically be changed to LargeIcon when `VirtualMode` is set to true.
>
> In virtual mode, the [`Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items.aspx) collection is disabled. Attempting to access it results in an [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx). The same is true of the [`CheckedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkeditems.aspx) collection and the [`SelectedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx) collection. If you want to retrieve the selected or checked items, use the [`SelectedIndices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices.aspx) and [`CheckedIndices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkedindices.aspx) collections instead.

Comment: I have done some research about this solution and I found the virtual mode don't exist in WPF :/ there's any way to do this solution in WPF

Comment: @Akrem: That's interesting. Your question didn't say anything at all about WPF. In fact, I tagged it `winforms` because it looked like you were talking about WinForms controls, not WPF ones. I suppose that was a mistake. No, I have no idea about WPF. Had you tagged the question WPF, I wouldn't have answered it.

Comment: @Cody Gray: the question was asked by alex dee but I have the same problem in WPF I didn't want to make a new question about the same thing (or I have to ?)

Comment: @Akrem: Ah, sorry. I assumed you were the original asker. I really have no idea about WPF, but it's likely that it doesn't have the same problem with a large number of items because of differences in its underlying technology. I never would have thought there'd be more than one person that needed to display more than 10,000 records at a time...

Comment: @Cody Gray: thx for your reply, in my datagrid I display in Max 500 records but the user have the choice between the start date and the finish date if he make a large period it maybe display more then 10.000 and it's a lot of information to get at once from database

Comment: @Akrem: Well, if the user requests that many records and it performs poorly because of it, that's their own fault. Virtual mode doesn't help when it comes to strain on your database, it just helps keep the app more responsive for the user.

Comment: Just a pointer to Akrems question:  [Display of records in datagrid takes time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655078/display-of-records-in-datagrid-takes-time)

Comment: @CodyGray "I really have no idea about WPF, but it's likely that it doesn't have the same problem with a large number of items because of differences in its underlying technology". Actually WPF has horrific performance problems with this because, fundamentally, its rendering pipeline has no support for visibility information and culling. I've hit this performance problem on every major WPF app I've ever worked on...

Answer (score 13):

Use a `FastObjectListView` from the [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) project.

50,000 rows is nothing, with automatic sorting, filtering, find-by-typing and loads of other goodness :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't. If you want to do something like this, load the first 500 rows and the last 100. When the user scrolls down a hundred rows, load the next batch automatically. On Ctrl+End, display the last 100 and preload the earlier batch in case the user scrolls up.

Play with the numbers until you get something that feels smooth for the user without actually loading 50K rows

Comment: This is, of course, what the virtual mode allows you to implement. Definitely don't do it manually by catching `KeyDown` events or something. That's way too fragile. There are tons of ways for users to scroll the controls. And it also isn't conducive to implementing a search function, which is *absolutely vital* for data of this quantity.

Comment: @Cody: Cool! I wasn't aware of the virtual mode. I agree it's clearly the way to go. For the search function, I don't understand the issue. Shouldn't it be implemented on the db itself rather than on the DGV?